# forEach in JavaScript not working collecting Object Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

The output of the following snippet should return the names of 5 cities in an array, but the result is a blank array. Why?

```js
arr = [
  {name: "London", population: 30},
  {name: "Moscow", population: 20},
  {name: "Delhi", population: 50},
  {name: "New York", population: 35},
  {name: "Paris", population: 42}
]

var temp = [];
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  temp.push[item.name];
});
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

use push(), not push[].

```js
arr = [
  {name: "London", population: 30},
  {name: "Moscow", population: 20},
  {name: "Delhi", population: 50},
  {name: "New York", population: 35},
  {name: "Paris", population: 42}
]

var temp = [];
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  temp.push(item.name);
});
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

`push` is a array method but you are using that as if it is an object having property  `item.name`. Instead of `[]` use `()` to invoke/call the method:

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "London", population: 30},
  {name: "Moscow", population: 20},
  {name: "Delhi", population: 50},
  {name: "New York", population: 35},
  {name: "Paris", population: 42}
]

var temp = [];
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  temp.push(item.name);
});

console.log(temp);
```

You can also try with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is much easier and cleaner:

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var arr = [
  {name: "London", population: 30},
  {name: "Moscow", population: 20},
  {name: "Delhi", population: 50},
  {name: "New York", population: 35},
  {name: "Paris", population: 42}
]

var temp = arr.map(i => i.name);
console.log(temp);
```